# Changing React state taking time so it takes old state in function logic

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have this function in my child component for deleting a document and its updating the state using `setDocumentList`. but when I delete 2-3 document by clicking very fast ,it's filtering from the initial state, i am not getting the updated state in the `newDocList` so my old document remain as it is. and UI updated for only last document because updating state taking time. so.. how to handle this situation please suggest any solution

Thanks in advance

```
    const deleteFile = (doc) => {

    Axios.delete(`url`).then((resp) => {
        let newDocList = [...documentList];
        newDocList = newDocList.filter(e => e.awsId != doc.awsId)
        setDocumentList(newDocList)
        if (props.onDocumentDeleted) props.onDocumentDeleted(newDocList)

    }).catch(error => {
        addMessageToDocUpload(doc, "Unable to delete file!", 'error')
    });

}
```

Comment: Please revise to use sentence punctuation. You have one long stream of words up there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the callback param when setting state that depends on previous state:

```
 const deleteFile = (doc) => {
    Axios.delete(`url`).then((resp) => {
        setDocumentList(prevDocList => prevDocList.filter(e => e.awsId != doc.awsId));

    }).catch(error => {
        addMessageToDocUpload(doc, "Unable to delete file!", 'error')
    });
```

Then add a useEffect to derived calculation once the new docs are updated:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        if (props.onDocumentDeleted) { props.onDocumentDeleted(newDocList) }
    },
    [documentList]
);
```

Comment: Not working still not able to delete multiple

Comment: No, not possible i need to setup with api and so many component , what happens in my code for last image, its gone into infinte loop, when last image deleted. its calling the useEffect method infinte time instead the document array have not any change

Comment: live:.cid.8f22757541a88ae4 connect on skype if possible will share my screen and show you